# Asyncio execution flow issue

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

i am a little new to asyncio in python. I was trying to run this simple code but i don't know why i am getting this unexpected output.

What i did is that, in `outer` function, i created async tasks and stored it in an array `tasks`. Before awaiting on these tasks i wrote a print statement `print("outer")` that should run in every iteration. And inside the task i wrote another print statement `print("inner")` in `inner` function. But some how i am getting some unexpected output.

Here's the code -

```
import asyncio


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(outer(loop))
    loop.close()


async def outer(loop):
    tasks = []
    for i in range(0, 5):
        tasks.append(loop.create_task(inner()))

    for task in tasks:
        print("outer")
        await task


async def inner():
    print("inner")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here's the output -

```
outer
inner
inner
inner
inner
inner
outer
outer
outer
outer
```

My Expected output was -

```
outer
inner
outer
inner
outer
inner
outer
inner
outer
inner
```

Why all the `inner` are printing before `outer`. What is the correct execution flow of asyncio. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each  task/coroutine *runs* up to the `await` statement then it gets suspended.. Your example is similar to the [coroutine example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) in the docs which has similar results.

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading) - `While a Task is running in the event loop, no other Tasks can run in the same thread. When a Task executes an await expression, the running Task gets suspended, and the event loop executes the next Task.`

Comment: But when one task gets awaited, then for starting a new task, event loop has to execute the next ```for``` loop iteration. If that is true, then ```outer``` should have be printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `async def outer(loop)`

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    tasks.append(loop.create_task(inner()))
```

- Five new `inner` tasks are created, scheduled and start running.
- the event loop runs the scheduled tasks till they are completed.

If you add a little bit more to to `inner` and `outer` it shows this process better:

```
async def outer(loop):
    tasks = []
    for i in range(0, 5):
        tasks.append(loop.create_task(inner(i)))
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    for task in tasks:
        print('outer')
        await task

async def inner(n):
    print(f"inner {n} start")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print(f'inner {n} end')
```

- while `outer` is sleeping

  - The first task *runs* to its await statement
  - The event loop suspends execution of the first task
  - The event loop *runs* the next scheduled task up to its await statement
  - This continues till each task has had a chance to run up to its await statement then the event loop starts looking around to see if any of the tasks are done waiting for whatever they were waiting for - if done it lets them run some more.
  - This continues till all the tasks are done
- You can see that the five tasks execute and finish before the second for loop even starts.
- in the second for loop each task has already completed so `await task` has nothing to wait for and `outer` is printed five times in succession.

I'm a little hazy on the event loop controlling everything - I haven't found any explicit documentation for that - probably alluded to in the `create_task` docs: `Wrap the coro coroutine into a Task and schedule its execution.` When you create the task it gets scheduled. I have seen videos on pyvideo.org that shows that process, unfortunately I couldn't quickly find the one I wanted to link to.

Comment: Did you find that pyvideo.org link where the complete process is explained?

Comment: @shikharsrivastava it eludes me. There are too many to watch/re-watch to find it. I may even be misremembering parts of many - thinking they are one.

Answer (score 2):

The `loop.create_task(inner())` *immediately* queues all 5 `inner` tasks for running, not `await task`. The `await task` suspends `outer` until the first task is *completely* done, i.e. at least 0.5 seconds. During this, all `inner` tasks have been run once up `await`, including their `print`.

---

```
async def outer(loop):
    tasks = []
    for i in range(0, 5):
        # queues task immediately
        tasks.append(loop.create_task(inner()))

    for task in tasks:
        print("outer")
        # suspends for at least 0.5 seconds
        await task


async def inner():
    # runs immediately
    print("inner")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: aha!!  If you add `await asyncio.sleep(10); print('outer done sleeping'` just after the loop that creates the tasks you can see that they run before any are awaited. thnx